# Please explain why a change in form is triggering run time error 3464

Tags: ms-access, vba, audit-trail

I am trying to teach myself more about Access so please forgive my ignorance of correct terminology/jargon. I want to put an audit trail in my database and have been using the code in the walk through [here](http://allenbrowne.com/AppAudit.html). It was working perfectly for me until I made some edits to the form. Now it is giving me a run time error 3464 on the 'db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError' line and I don't understand what change I have made that is causing this. Please and thanks in advance for any/all assistance !

Code is below,

```
    Option Compare Database
   Dim bWasNewRecord As Boolean

Private Sub Form_Delete(Cancel As Integer)
   Call AuditDelBegin("Employee", "audTmpEmployee", "db_number", Nz(Me.EmployeeID, 0))

End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
   Call AuditDelEnd("audTmpEmployee", "audEmployee", Status)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   bWasNewRecord = Me.NewRecord
   Call AuditEditBegin("Employee", "audTmpEmployee", "db_number", Nz(Me.db_number, 0), bWasNewRecord)

End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Call AuditEditEnd("Employee", "audTmpEmployee", "audEmployee", "db_number", Nz(Me!db_number, 0), bWasNewRecord)

End Sub

Private Sub Reset_Click()
  DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec



End Sub


Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const conMod As String = "ajbAudit"
Private Declare Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
    "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long


Function NetworkUserName() As String
'On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim lngLen As Long
    Dim lngX As Long
    Dim strUserName As String

    NetworkUserName = "Unknown"

    strUserName = String$(254, 0)
    lngLen = 255&
    lngX = apiGetUserName(strUserName, lngLen)
    If (lngX > 0&) Then
        NetworkUserName = Left$(strUserName, lngLen - 1&)
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, conMod & ".NetworkUserName", , False)
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function


Function AuditDelBegin(sTable As String, sAudTmpTable As String, sKeyField As String,         
lngKeyValue As Long) As Boolean
'On Error GoTo Err_AuditDelBegin

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim sSQL As String

    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sAudTmpTable & " ( audType, audDate, audUser ) " & _
        "SELECT 'Delete' AS Expr1, Now() AS Expr2, NetworkUserName() AS Expr3, " &         sTable & ".* " & _
        "FROM " & sTable & " WHERE (" & sTable & "." & sKeyField & " = " & lngKeyValue & ");"
    db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError

Exit_AuditDelBegin:
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_AuditDelBegin:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, conMod & ".AuditDelBegin()", , False)
    Resume Exit_AuditDelBegin
End Function


Function AuditDelEnd(sAudTmpTable As String, sAudTable As String, Status As Integer) As     Boolean
'On Error GoTo Err_AuditDelEnd
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim sSQL As String

    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    If Status = acDeleteOK Then
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sAudTable & " SELECT " & sAudTmpTable & ".* FROM " &     sAudTmpTable & _
            " WHERE (" & sAudTmpTable & ".audType = 'Delete');"
        db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
    End If

    sSQL = "DELETE FROM " & sAudTmpTable & ";"
    db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
    AuditDelEnd = True

Exit_AuditDelEnd:
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_AuditDelEnd:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, conMod & ".AuditDelEnd()", False)
    Resume Exit_AuditDelEnd
End Function


Function AuditEditBegin(sTable As String, sAudTmpTable As String, sKeyField As String, _
    lngKeyValue As Long, bWasNewRecord As Boolean) As Boolean
'On Error GoTo Err_AuditEditBegin

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim sSQL As String

    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    sSQL = "DELETE FROM " & sAudTmpTable & ";"
    db.Execute sSQL


    If Not bWasNewRecord Then
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sAudTmpTable & " ( audType, audDate, audUser ) " & _
            "SELECT 'EditFrom' AS Expr1, Now() AS Expr2, NetworkUserName() AS Expr3, " & sTable & ".* " & _
            "FROM " & sTable & " WHERE (" & sTable & "." & sKeyField & " = " &     lngKeyValue & ");"
        db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
    End If
    AuditEditBegin = True

Exit_AuditEditBegin:
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_AuditEditBegin:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, conMod & ".AuditEditBegin()", , False)
    Resume Exit_AuditEditBegin
End Function


    Function AuditEditEnd(sTable As String, sAudTmpTable As String, sAudTable As String, _
    sKeyField As String, lngKeyValue As Long, bWasNewRecord As Boolean) As Boolean
'On Error GoTo Err_AuditEditEnd

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim sSQL As String
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)

    If bWasNewRecord Then

        sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sAudTable & " ( audType, audDate, audUser ) " & _
            "SELECT 'Insert' AS Expr1, Now() AS Expr2, NetworkUserName() AS Expr3, " & sTable & ".* " & _
            "FROM " & sTable & " WHERE (" & sTable & "." & sKeyField & " = " & lngKeyValue & ");"
        db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
    Else

        sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sAudTable & " SELECT TOP 1 " & sAudTmpTable & ".* FROM " & sAudTmpTable & _
            " WHERE (" & sAudTmpTable & ".audType = 'EditFrom') ORDER BY " & sAudTmpTable & ".audDate DESC;"
        db.Execute sSQL

        sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sAudTable & " ( audType, audDate, audUser ) " & _
            "SELECT 'EditTo' AS Expr1, Now() AS Expr2, NetworkUserName() AS Expr3, " & sTable & ".* " & _
            "FROM " & sTable & " WHERE (" & sTable & "." & sKeyField & " = " & lngKeyValue & ");"
        db.Execute sSQL
        ' Empty the temp table.
        sSQL = "DELETE FROM " & sAudTmpTable & ";"
        db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
    End If
    AuditEditEnd = True

Exit_AuditEditEnd:
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_AuditEditEnd:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, conMod & ".AuditEditEnd()", , False)
    Resume Exit_AuditEditEnd
End Function
```

Comment: Error #3464 is *"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."* It means there is a problem with the SQL statement. Examine your `sSQL` string when `db.Execute` fails.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that in the `INSERT INTO` you defined 3 fields while you are apssing 4 fields with the `SELECT` part.
When doing an `INSERT INTO` query, in the `VALUES/SELECT` part you need to match all the columns qualified in the query (and the right order), (if no columns where qualified, then all the columns must be accounted for (in the case of a `SELECT` if the columns of the second table matches the first then it's good as well).
I marked the issue in **bold** (edit: I see that the bold doesn't show in a `code` block, I marked it being wrapped in `**`).
`sSQL = "INSERT INTO " & sAudTmpTable & " ( **audType, audDate, audUser** ) " & _ "SELECT 'Delete' AS Expr1, Now() AS Expr2, NetworkUserName() AS Expr3, " **& sTable & ".* "** & _ "FROM " & sTable & " WHERE (" & sTable & "." & sKeyField & " = " & lngKeyValue & ");" db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError`

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Why would it have been working perfectly well until I changed the form?